# Determining intervals and concavity

Tags: calculus

I came across this question:

> Given the function $f(x)=2x^6+9x^5+10x^4−13x−5$, determine all intervals on which the graph of f is concave up, all intervals where it is concave down, and find all inflection points for f.

How do you find the intervals? And how do you know if they're concave up/down? I've tried but my results don't make any sense... Could anyone show me the process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

> If $f(x)$ is twice-differentiable, then $f(x)$ is concave (down) if
>   and only if $f ′′(x)$ is non-positive.

([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Properties))

And we have, for your function:
$$
f''(x)=60x^2(x^2+3x+2)
$$

Can you verify this and find the intervals wher it is not positive?

---

A necessary condition for a differentiable function to have an inflexion point at $x=x_0$ is that $f''(x_0)=0$. So, for your function, you can see that the possible inflexion points are for $x=-2$,$x=-1$ and $x=0$. But this condition is not sufficient. As you can see in the image that represents the graph of your function ( the $y$ axis is scaled to reduce the image) for $x=0$ there is not inflexion point.

[image]

In fact:

> if  $f''(x_0)=0$, $x_0$ is an inflexion point only if the first non
>   null successive derivative is of odd order.

In your case you can easily find that $f''' (0)=0$, and $f^{IV}(0) \ne 0$ so this condition is not verified.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried it and found the function to be concave down on (-2;-1), or between the roots, and concave up for the rest. Is that right?

Comment: Also, how can I find the inflection points for the function? I understand that it's according to where the first derivative is zero, but it's such a complicated function, how can I find the values for the Xs ? Thanks!

Comment: @ArthurRimbaud. This can be another question. Anyway... I've added something to my answer. I hope it's helpfull :)